# Inconsistent behaviour of StrTokenizer to split string

Tags: java, string, split, quotes

I'm trying to split a string at a given delimiter allowing for delimiters to be inside quotes to be ignored. E.g.

`"foo; bar; 'foo; bar'"`

Should be slitted into 3 strings given delimiter ';' and quote char ':

`foo
bar
foo; bar`

I'm using [StrTokenizer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrTokenizer.html) as below but it doesn't seem to work for `"foo; bar; 'foo; bar'"` but it does work for `"'foo; bar'; foo; bar;"`

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrTokenizer;
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String x= "foo; bar; 'foo; bar'";

        StrTokenizer tokens= new StrTokenizer(x, ';', '\'');

        for (String token : tokens.getTokenArray()) {
            System.out.println(token.trim());
        }
        // Prints:
        // foo
        // bar
        // 'foo
        // bar'

        /* --------- */
        // THIS IS OK:
        x= "'foo; bar'; foo; bar";

        tokens= new StrTokenizer(x, ';', '\'');

        for (String token : tokens.getTokenArray()) {
            System.out.println(token.trim());
        }
        // Prints:
        // foo; bar
        // foo
        // bar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like by default quoted area can't be preceded by any character (even space) except delimiter (so `; 'quote'` is not OK, but `;'qupte'` is fine) - (which is little strange because space between end of quote and delimiter doesn't seem to cause any problem, which may suggest that this may be a bug).

Explicitly setting characters which should be trimmed seems to solve this problem (also you no longer need to add `trim()` in your printing statements):

```
StrTokenizer tokens = new StrTokenizer(x, ';', '\'');
tokens.setTrimmerMatcher(StrMatcher.spaceMatcher());// <- add this line
```

To trim on: space, tab, newline and formfeed use `StrMatcher.splitMatcher()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a bit surprised that such (common?) task requires such counterintuitive coding (IMHO). Most solutions I found involve regexes which I tried to avoid for this. By the way, I don't need to stick to StrTokenizer, I'd be happy to switch to better options if any...

Comment: Hmm, better options could depend on what you are really doing. At first I though that you are trying to parse CSV file so maybe some CVS parser would be better tool, but delimiters in such files don't have any unnecessary characters which would require trimming (so you wouldn't even end up in this situation). But maybe there are better CVS parsers which could simplify your task that I am not aware of.

Comment: No, not a CSV file. I just need to split a string that vaguely could look like a command line argument. StrTokenizer seemed to do exactly what I wanted until I tripped on the test case above, which is quite basic really.